# Do inline markup options have influence on SEO?

Tags: seo, html

```
<div class="super-accordion" data-super-accordion="{collapse:false,duration:200}">
....
</div>
...
<ul class="cool-tab" data-cool-tab="{connect:'#some-id', animation:'slide-top',duration:250}">
    <li><a href="">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

Those examples are common with some open-source JS libs.

Does those inline options impact search engines? compared to those options compiled in js/css files?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Long answer: nooooooooooooo

Comment: @Rob You cracked me up! That is something I would do... (sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all, What counts for a search engine is textual content, it will filter out everything else.

Here is an article on how js is handled by search engine giant Google :

http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157